# Routing in A child compoent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a nested route system, One is in App.js and one in RoomGuard component
The app.js has router to render roomGuard and roomGuard has the route to render other child component But it is not happening
how to solve this.

console.js:213 No routes matched location "/posts"

```
const App = () => {
  const linkName = ["Developer", "Post"];
  const linkPath = ["/profiles", "/post"];

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Navbar name={linkName} link={linkPath} />
        <ToastContainer />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route element={<RoomGuard />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const RoomGuard = () => {
  const socket = useMemo (()=> io("http://localhost:5000"))

  useEffect(() => {

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect()
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/profiles"
        element={
          <AuthGuard>
            <LoggedInUser>
              <Profiles />
            </LoggedInUser>
          </AuthGuard>
        }
      ></Route>
      
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default RoomGuard;
```

I was epecting to route trhough component in the roomGuard component same as normal router does.

Comment: where is your `/posts` route?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `"/posts"` route rendered anywhere in the code you specific, so I'm assuming you meant the descendent `"/profiles"` route in `RoomGuard`.

The `RoomGuard` route needs to specify a trailing wildcard, i.e. splat, `"*"` character in order for descendent routes to be matched and rendered.

```
const App = () => {
  const linkName = ["Developer", "Post"];
  const linkPath = ["/profiles", "/post"];

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Navbar name={linkName} link={linkPath} />
        <ToastContainer />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route
              path="*" // <-- allow matching descendent routes 
              element={<RoomGuard />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help my problem is solved, really really appreciate you.